How to optimize the nested inner loop join and sort in postgres
I've 2 tables in my database as defined below -
CREATE TABLE metric_events (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    metric_id integer NOT NULL,
    event_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    code text NOT NULL, 
    test boolean DEFAULT false NOT NULL,
    success boolean DEFAULT false NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE hourly_metric_event_counters (
    start_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    metric_id integer NOT NULL,
    code text NOT NULL,
    test boolean NOT NULL,
    total_count integer DEFAULT 0,
    success_count integer DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (metric_id, test, code, start_at)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX metric_events_uuid_index ON metric_events(id);
CREATE INDEX metric_events_event_at_index on metric_events(event_at);
CREATE INDEX metric_events_metric_id_and_event_at_index ON metric_events(metric_id, event_at);
CREATE INDEX hourly_metric_event_counters_start_at_index ON hourly_metric_event_counters(start_at);


Then I've to run this query once daily -
SELECT date_trunc('hour', b.event_at),
       b.metric_id,
       b.code,
       b.test,
       COUNT(b.*) - MAX(bec.total_count) as total_diff,
       SUM(CASE WHEN b.success THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - MAX(bec.success_count) as success_diff
FROM metric_events b
JOIN hourly_metric_event_counters bec
ON bec.metric_id = b.metric_id AND
   bec.test = b.test AND
   bec.code = b.code AND
   bec.start_at = date_trunc('hour', b.event_at)
WHERE event_at >= date_trunc('hour', NOW() - interval '24 hours') AND event_at < date_trunc('hour', NOW() - interval '1 hour')
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
HAVING COUNT(b.*) - MAX(bec.total_count) != 0 OR
       SUM(CASE WHEN b.success THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - MAX(bec.success_count) != 0

Eventhough the query works it takes 12 minutes to complete.
When I explain the query I got the below output -

Is there any way I can optimize my query by adding some other indexes?
Here are some statistics -
total records count in metric_events - 246394965
records count in last 24 hours - 46524166
total records in hourly_metric_event_counters - 70559661
records count in hourly_metric_event_counters last 24 hours - 26054
Query Plan is -
"QUERY PLAN"
"Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=5874097.11..6142178.38 rows=1641905 width=33) (actual time=549422.104..553266.628 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  Output: (date_trunc('hour'::text, b.event_at)), b.metric_id, b.code, b.test, (count(b.*) - max(bec.total_count)), (sum(CASE WHEN b.success THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - max(bec.success_count))"
"  Group Key: (date_trunc('hour'::text, b.event_at)), b.metric_id, b.code, b.test"
"  Filter: (((count(b.*) - max(bec.total_count)) <> 0) OR ((sum(CASE WHEN b.success THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - max(bec.success_count)) <> 0))"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 26077"
"  Buffers: shared hit=38710381 read=221036, temp read=5217342 written=5239543"
"  I/O Timings: read=4538289.329"
"  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=5874097.11..6055976.54 rows=1368288 width=41) (actual time=511468.544..553250.834 rows=26091 loops=1)"
"        Output: (date_trunc('hour'::text, b.event_at)), b.metric_id, b.code, b.test, (PARTIAL count(b.*)), (PARTIAL max(bec.total_count)), (PARTIAL sum(CASE WHEN b.success THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)), (PARTIAL max(bec.success_count))"
"        Workers Planned: 2"
"        Workers Launched: 2"
"        Buffers: shared hit=38710381 read=221036, temp read=5217342 written=5239543"
"        I/O Timings: read=4538289.329"
"        ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=5873097.09..5897042.13 rows=684144 width=41) (actual time=466314.905..497064.836 rows=8697 loops=3)"
"              Output: (date_trunc('hour'::text, b.event_at)), b.metric_id, b.code, b.test, PARTIAL count(b.*), PARTIAL max(bec.total_count), PARTIAL sum(CASE WHEN b.success THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), PARTIAL max(bec.success_count)"
"              Group Key: (date_trunc('hour'::text, b.event_at)), b.metric_id, b.code, b.test"
"              Buffers: shared hit=38710381 read=221036, temp read=5217342 written=5239543"
"              I/O Timings: read=4538289.329"
"              Worker 0:  actual time=424291.981..458861.165 rows=9233 loops=1"
"                Buffers: shared hit=12954922 read=69069, temp read=1611879 written=1636822"
"                I/O Timings: read=1497818.970"
"              Worker 1:  actual time=463185.340..496780.017 rows=9054 loops=1"
"                Buffers: shared hit=12887610 read=76010, temp read=1676189 written=1689592"
"                I/O Timings: read=1519095.858"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=5873097.09..5874807.45 rows=684144 width=265) (actual time=466314.876..493638.027 rows=15798589 loops=3)"
"                    Output: (date_trunc('hour'::text, b.event_at)), b.metric_id, b.code, b.test, b.*, bec.total_count, b.success, bec.success_count"
"                    Sort Key: (date_trunc('hour'::text, b.event_at)), b.metric_id, b.code, b.test"
"                    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2770024kB"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=38710381 read=221036, temp read=5217342 written=5239543"
"                    I/O Timings: read=4538289.329"
"                    Worker 0:  actual time=424291.945..455695.296 rows=14521485 loops=1"
"                      Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2310496kB"
"                      Buffers: shared hit=12954922 read=69069, temp read=1611879 written=1636822"
"                      I/O Timings: read=1497818.970"
"                    Worker 1:  actual time=463185.314..493480.652 rows=15255740 loops=1"
"                      Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2413136kB"
"                      Buffers: shared hit=12887610 read=76010, temp read=1676189 written=1689592"
"                      I/O Timings: read=1519095.858"
"                    ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=1665082.59..5633743.05 rows=684144 width=265) (actual time=86709.198..217236.864 rows=15798589 loops=3)"
"                          Output: date_trunc('hour'::text, b.event_at), b.metric_id, b.code, b.test, b.*, bec.total_count, b.success, bec.success_count"
"                          Inner Unique: true"
"                          Hash Cond: ((b.metric_id = bec.metric_id) AND (b.test = bec.test) AND (b.code = bec.code) AND (date_trunc('hour'::text, b.event_at) = bec.start_at))"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=38710321 read=221036, temp read=1373870 written=1392584"
"                          I/O Timings: read=4538289.329"
"                          Worker 0:  actual time=86770.465..217783.818 rows=14521485 loops=1"
"                            Buffers: shared hit=12954892 read=69069, temp read=443351 written=467224"
"                            I/O Timings: read=1497818.970"
"                          Worker 1:  actual time=86594.197..217367.564 rows=15255740 loops=1"
"                            Buffers: shared hit=12887580 read=76010, temp read=453129 written=465408"
"                            I/O Timings: read=1519095.858"
"                          ->  Parallel Index Scan using metric_events_event_at_idx on public.metric_events b  (cost=0.58..2150647.47 rows=19938562 width=257) (actual time=4.382..20018.921 rows=15798589 loops=3)"
"                                Output: b.event_at, b.metric_id, b.code, b.test, b.*, b.success"
"                                Index Cond: ((b.event_at >= date_trunc('hour'::text, (now() - '24:00:00'::interval))) AND (b.event_at < date_trunc('hour'::text, (now() - '01:00:00'::interval))))"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=38260163 read=97367"
"                                I/O Timings: read=457489.471"
"                                Worker 0:  actual time=4.907..19871.843 rows=15856727 loops=1"
"                                  Buffers: shared hit=12799546 read=30842"
"                                  I/O Timings: read=149719.538"
"                                Worker 1:  actual time=2.685..20049.103 rows=15779628 loops=1"
"                                  Buffers: shared hit=12738663 read=33865"
"                                  I/O Timings: read=152223.425"
"                          ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=870032.00..870032.00 rows=29626300 width=25) (actual time=28441.654..28441.656 rows=23520925 loops=3)"
"                                Output: bec.total_count, bec.success_count, bec.metric_id, bec.test, bec.code, bec.start_at"
"                                Buckets: 65536  Batches: 2048  Memory Usage: 2752kB"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=450100 read=123669, temp written=461076"
"                                I/O Timings: read=4080799.858"
"                                Worker 0:  actual time=28436.181..28436.183 rows=23862695 loops=1"
"                                  Buffers: shared hit=155317 read=38227, temp written=155584"
"                                  I/O Timings: read=1348099.432"
"                                Worker 1:  actual time=28441.555..28441.556 rows=23590681 loops=1"
"                                  Buffers: shared hit=148888 read=42145, temp written=155292"
"                                  I/O Timings: read=1366872.433"
"                                ->  Parallel Seq Scan on public.hourly_metric_event_counters bec  (cost=0.00..870032.00 rows=29626300 width=25) (actual time=1.786..6127.575 rows=23520925 loops=3)"
"                                      Output: bec.total_count, bec.success_count, bec.metric_id, bec.test, bec.code, bec.start_at"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=450100 read=123669"
"                                      I/O Timings: read=4080799.858"
"                                      Worker 0:  actual time=1.047..6091.280 rows=23862695 loops=1"
"                                        Buffers: shared hit=155317 read=38227"
"                                        I/O Timings: read=1348099.432"
"                                      Worker 1:  actual time=1.972..6380.737 rows=23590681 loops=1"
"                                        Buffers: shared hit=148888 read=42145"
"                                        I/O Timings: read=1366872.433"
"Settings: effective_cache_size = '21552912kB', maintenance_io_concurrency = '1'"
"Planning:"
"  Buffers: shared hit=59 read=21"
"  I/O Timings: read=18.206"
"Planning Time: 19.833 ms"
"Execution Time: 553592.098 ms"


after setting set enable_parallel_append = off; the result is -
"QUERY PLAN"
"Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=5039350.45..5251574.80 rows=1299801 width=33) (actual time=500634.040..504406.583 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  Output: (date_trunc('hour'::text, b.event_at)), b.metric_id, b.code, b.test, (count(b.*) - max(bec.total_count)), (sum(CASE WHEN b.success THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - max(bec.success_count))"
"  Group Key: (date_trunc('hour'::text, b.event_at)), b.metric_id, b.code, b.test"
"  Filter: (((count(b.*) - max(bec.total_count)) <> 0) OR ((sum(CASE WHEN b.success THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - max(bec.success_count)) <> 0))"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 19558"
"  Buffers: shared hit=35367129 read=10287, temp read=4846972 written=4869717"
"  I/O Timings: read=48111.193"
"  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=5039350.45..5183333.81 rows=1083194 width=41) (actual time=472908.579..504391.139 rows=19578 loops=1)"
"        Output: (date_trunc('hour'::text, b.event_at)), b.metric_id, b.code, b.test, (PARTIAL count(b.*)), (PARTIAL max(bec.total_count)), (PARTIAL sum(CASE WHEN b.success THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)), (PARTIAL max(bec.success_count))"
"        Workers Planned: 2"
"        Workers Launched: 2"
"        Buffers: shared hit=35367129 read=10287, temp read=4846972 written=4869717"
"        I/O Timings: read=48111.193"
"        ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=5038350.43..5057306.32 rows=541597 width=41) (actual time=449313.739..472880.352 rows=6526 loops=3)"
"              Output: (date_trunc('hour'::text, b.event_at)), b.metric_id, b.code, b.test, PARTIAL count(b.*), PARTIAL max(bec.total_count), PARTIAL sum(CASE WHEN b.success THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), PARTIAL max(bec.success_count)"
"              Group Key: (date_trunc('hour'::text, b.event_at)), b.metric_id, b.code, b.test"
"              Buffers: shared hit=35367129 read=10287, temp read=4846972 written=4869717"
"              I/O Timings: read=48111.193"
"              Worker 0:  actual time=471833.966..492689.822 rows=6338 loops=1"
"                Buffers: shared hit=11813010 read=2399, temp read=1648777 written=1656100"
"                I/O Timings: read=10744.978"
"              Worker 1:  actual time=403199.162..432016.328 rows=6605 loops=1"
"                Buffers: shared hit=11742379 read=2743, temp read=1575086 written=1582865"
"                I/O Timings: read=15733.895"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=5038350.43..5039704.42 rows=541597 width=265) (actual time=449313.631..469582.364 rows=14591820 loops=3)"
"                    Output: (date_trunc('hour'::text, b.event_at)), b.metric_id, b.code, b.test, b.*, bec.total_count, b.success, bec.success_count"
"                    Sort Key: (date_trunc('hour'::text, b.event_at)), b.metric_id, b.code, b.test"
"                    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2331160kB"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=35367129 read=10287, temp read=4846972 written=4869717"
"                    I/O Timings: read=48111.193"
"                    Worker 0:  actual time=471833.936..489361.413 rows=14631751 loops=1"
"                      Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2311720kB"
"                      Buffers: shared hit=11813010 read=2399, temp read=1648777 written=1656100"
"                      I/O Timings: read=10744.978"
"                    Worker 1:  actual time=403198.894..428711.353 rows=14367995 loops=1"
"                      Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2265712kB"
"                      Buffers: shared hit=11742379 read=2743, temp read=1575086 written=1582865"
"                      I/O Timings: read=15733.895"
"                    ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=1668184.53..4849781.81 rows=541597 width=265) (actual time=81770.741..204394.735 rows=14591820 loops=3)"
"                          Output: date_trunc('hour'::text, b.event_at), b.metric_id, b.code, b.test, b.*, bec.total_count, b.success, bec.success_count"
"                          Inner Unique: true"
"                          Hash Cond: ((b.metric_id = bec.metric_id) AND (b.test = bec.test) AND (b.code = bec.code) AND (date_trunc('hour'::text, b.event_at) = bec.start_at))"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=35367069 read=10287, temp read=1302249 written=1321408"
"                          I/O Timings: read=48111.193"
"                          Worker 0:  actual time=81676.679..204072.459 rows=14631751 loops=1"
"                            Buffers: shared hit=11812980 read=2399, temp read=432462 written=438420"
"                            I/O Timings: read=10744.978"
"                          Worker 1:  actual time=81805.972..204492.863 rows=14367995 loops=1"
"                            Buffers: shared hit=11742349 read=2743, temp read=433440 written=440164"
"                            I/O Timings: read=15733.895"
"                          ->  Parallel Index Scan using metric_events_event_at_idx on public.metric_events b  (cost=0.59..1705616.28 rows=15712433 width=257) (actual time=0.120..17219.944 rows=14591820 loops=3)"
"                                Output: b.event_at, b.metric_id, b.code, b.test, b.*, b.success"
"                                Index Cond: ((b.event_at >= date_trunc('hour'::text, (now() - '24:00:00'::interval))) AND (b.event_at < date_trunc('hour'::text, (now() - '01:00:00'::interval))))"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=34792293 read=10167"
"                                I/O Timings: read=47557.563"
"                                Worker 0:  actual time=0.152..17339.673 rows=14624825 loops=1"
"                                  Buffers: shared hit=11624291 read=2379"
"                                  I/O Timings: read=10669.721"
"                                Worker 1:  actual time=0.085..17235.515 rows=14536999 loops=1"
"                                  Buffers: shared hit=11553401 read=2726"
"                                  I/O Timings: read=15518.850"
"                          ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=871652.98..871652.98 rows=29681498 width=25) (actual time=28496.651..28496.652 rows=23527913 loops=3)"
"                                Output: bec.total_count, bec.success_count, bec.metric_id, bec.test, bec.code, bec.start_at"
"                                Buckets: 65536  Batches: 2048  Memory Usage: 2752kB"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=574718 read=120, temp written=461280"
"                                I/O Timings: read=553.630"
"                                Worker 0:  actual time=28495.025..28495.026 rows=23166312 loops=1"
"                                  Buffers: shared hit=188660 read=20, temp written=151120"
"                                  I/O Timings: read=75.257"
"                                Worker 1:  actual time=28495.086..28495.087 rows=23419789 loops=1"
"                                  Buffers: shared hit=188919 read=17, temp written=154464"
"                                  I/O Timings: read=215.045"
"                                ->  Parallel Seq Scan on public.hourly_metric_event_counters bec  (cost=0.00..871652.98 rows=29681498 width=25) (actual time=0.953..5576.380 rows=23527913 loops=3)"
"                                      Output: bec.total_count, bec.success_count, bec.metric_id, bec.test, bec.code, bec.start_at"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=574718 read=120"
"                                      I/O Timings: read=553.630"
"                                      Worker 0:  actual time=1.036..5557.437 rows=23166312 loops=1"
"                                        Buffers: shared hit=188660 read=20"
"                                        I/O Timings: read=75.257"
"                                      Worker 1:  actual time=0.829..5572.386 rows=23419789 loops=1"
"                                        Buffers: shared hit=188919 read=17"
"                                        I/O Timings: read=215.045"
"Settings: effective_cache_size = '21552912kB', enable_parallel_append = 'off', maintenance_io_concurrency = '1'"
"Planning:"
"  Buffers: shared hit=36 read=24"
"  I/O Timings: read=21.090"
"Planning Time: 22.133 ms"
"Execution Time: 504680.682 ms"

Note: Database version is -
PostgreSQL 13.4 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc (GCC) 7.4.0, 64-bit

Could you please use explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) and share the result in plain text? Your current image isn't very helpful, it's missing all the details.

@FrankHeikens I've added the query plan as you mentioned in the post.

13.4 is very old, the latest is 13.14.

Your plan is weird.  How can an index scan which only lasted  20 seconds have spent 457 seconds waiting on IO?  There is a 3-fold parallelization, but this is 7.5 fold away from being able to explain it.

To me it looks like your IO is fairly limited, just a few MB per second. What happens when you turn enable_parallel_append of? That would make all IO resources available for a single proces. Besides that, work_mem is too small and you should increase that as well. A covering index on the columns date_trunc('hour', event_at), metric_id, code, test could be beneficial.

@FrankHeikens - I've updated the query plan after setting enable_parallel_append off?

You still got concurrency, see Workers Planned: 2. Turn it all off, you don't have the resources for it. Did you already create the single index for all 4 columns? And did you change the setting for work_mem? You now sort on disk, and your disk is already slow. Your current query plan sorts GB's of data on a slow disk. Over 50% of the time is spent on sorting. A better index might get rid of the need for a sort: Sort Key: (date_trunc('hour'::text, b.event_at)), b.metric_id, b.code, b.test

I increased the work_mem to 1GB. Now the query executes in 4 mins. I couldn't create the composite index CREATE INDEX metric_events_composite_index on metric_events (metric_id, code, test, success, date_trunc('hour'::text, event_at)); returns error - ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE
SQL state: 42P17. Any idea how to fix this?
